# Transform distance or create view using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a PostGIS table that is updated on a regular basis so it is not practical to cast my geometry column to geography

So can I modify the following query to convert a distance say 0.5k into  decimal Degrees on the fly at the latitude of the given point?

```
Select colA,colB,lat_dms,long_dms 
FROM
my_geo_table
WHERE
ST_DWithin(SRID=4326;POINT(LONG LAT)’,geom,0.5);
```

I would be replacing 0.5 which in above equals 30 minutes with ST_Transform(500) but am unsure of the syntax

Or would I be better of creating and saving a VIEW?

```
CREATE VIEW geog_from_geom_view 
Select colA,colB,lat_dms,long_dms 
FROM
my_geo_table;

ALTER TABLE geog_from_geom_view  ADD column geog;
Update geog_from_geom_view set geog = ST__GeographyFromText(ST_as_Text(my_geo_table.geom));
```

I tried above but cauld not make it work I kept getting an error saying geog_from_geom_view is not a table

also tried ALTER VIEW with Same error

If I created a View what would the Syntax of the new query be?

I’m on windows 7 using pgAdmin  PostGIS 2.0 with no CMD line access

To answer the questions martin f
1)

> decimal DMS

Should be decimal Degrees

2)

> the 500 in ST_Transform() an SRID?

no it is 0.5k in meters
so should it be ST_Transform(POINT, 500, 4326);

but that doesn't make sense when I'm trying to find all points within 0.5k of a given LAT Long

---

in PgAdmin I created a view  my view definition now looks like this

```
select colA,colB,lat_dms,long_dms ,geom
FROM
my_geo_table,
Geog GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326),
geom::geography AS geog;
```

I now get an syntax error at or near “4326”
LINE 4 Geog GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a view that casts one datatype to another, it's simple, just use `::newdatatype` in the select part of the query:

```
CREATE VIEW geog_from_geom_view 
  SELECT gid, geom::geography AS geog, cola, colb
  FROM my_geo_table;
```

But with the original table `my_geo_table`, it doesn't make any specific performance difference whether the location is stored as a `geometry` or `geography` type. [Pick one based on what you need](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry). You can even make an insert/update trigger to cast the object from the numeric lat/long data.

To select data [within](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html) 0.5 km (500 m) of a point, you can either cast a `geography` from the query, or use the view.

```
SELECT * FROM my_geo_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_MakePoint(:LONG, :LAT), 500.0);

-- or

SELECT * FROM geog_from_geom_view
WHERE ST_DWithin(geog, ST_MakePoint(:LONG, :LAT), 500.0);
```

Neither of these will have great query performance, since they will need to cast the geometry for the whole table and do a sequence scan (slow). To improve it there are few options, such as using an [index based on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html), or store geography types instead of geometry types. Adding an index, however, would make frequent table updates slower.